# Animation in swift : Circular Dashed Loading Bar?

Tags: ios, animation, swift3, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have literally looked over the web for like 2to3 hours, unfortunately couldn't find anything, (2nd problem: being new to swift ->this can be ignored)

> **Basically I need Circular dashed Loading bar : Every dot should animate Individually like a circular load..**

I was able to make a circular dashed circle but couldn't animate it...

Any help would be appreciated even if thats an library from github or anything..

Here's my code for creating a circular dashed circle..

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 100,y: 100), radius: 100.0, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 6.0
    let one : NSNumber = 1
    let two : NSNumber = 13
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [one,two]
    shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() { super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()}
}
```

[image: thats what I got]

> **This is what I want (Below One):**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been playing around with custom activity indicators, so here's one way to do it

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class ActivityIndicatorCircle: UIView {
    var  timerInterval: Double   = 0.1
    var timer : Timer?
    var endAngle: CGFloat   = 0.0
    var angleStep           = CGFloat.pi / 20.0
    var angleOffset         = -CGFloat.pi / 2.0

    var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    func startAnimating() {
        superview?.bringSubview(toFront: self)

        layer.cornerRadius = frame.width / 2
        self.clipsToBounds = true

        isHidden = false
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timerInterval,
                                 target: self,
                                 selector: #selector(self.updateCircle),
                                 userInfo: nil,
                                 repeats: true)
    }

    func stopAnimating() {
        isHidden = true
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }

    func updateCircle() {
        endAngle += angleStep
        if endAngle > CGFloat.pi * 2.0 {
            endAngle -= CGFloat.pi * 2.0
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.shapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer() // remove the previous version

            let lineWidth: CGFloat = 6.0
            let radius = self.frame.size.width / 2.0 // if the view is square, this gives us center as well

            let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: radius,y: radius), radius: radius - lineWidth, startAngle: self.angleOffset, endAngle: self.endAngle + self.angleOffset, clockwise: true)

            self.shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
            self.shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            self.shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            self.shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            self.shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
            let one : NSNumber = 1
            let two : NSNumber = 13
            self.shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [one,two]
            self.shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
            self.layer.addSublayer(self.shapeLayer)
        }
    }
}
```

to use this, add a UIView to your storyboard, and set the class to `ActivityIndicatorCircle`

To start it, call `activityIndicatorCircle.startAnimating()`

Comment: Hey russell thanks for the answer Man.!
Can you give more information about that..
I mean its not working , whatever you said I did that.
I'd created a object for ActivityIndicatorCircle in viewDidAppear of Viewcontroller.swift and in storyBoard have assigned the class to that view..Still not wokring.

Comment: I have created a sample project for you https://github.com/CarterMiller/ActivityIndicatorCircle .  Because I based the circle indicator on one I had already done, you can see how I did the others in the same project :-)

Comment: Whoa ! Thanku Mr.russell ..
It had solved the problem.. Thank you so much.
Just because of you people Communities like stackoverflow and such exists..
Keep up the good work =D =)

Comment: Hello Mr.Russel,

Answer (score 0):

for circular loader you can use this library it will help you. https://github.com/naoyashiga/RPLoadingAnimation

Comment: Thank you for replying super fast bro..
as per my requirements your answer dosn't work.. 
_/\_